# How many quadrilaterals can be made using 4 points on a 5x5 dot grid?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This is from some general combinatorics work I have been doing.
To specify, the dot grid looks something like this (excuse the rudimentary approach):
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet\\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet\\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet\\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet\\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet
\end{array}$$

While I can get around finding the number of triangles and rectangles that can be made with 4 dots, what has stumped me is general quadrilaterals.

Thanks.

Comment: For every four points such that no three out of the four are colinear, observe a complete graph $K_4$. If the edges of that graph intersect somewhere other than in the vertices, count $1$ additional convex quadrilateral. Otherwise, count $3$ additional concave quadrilaterals.

Comment: What is the source of your question? It seems computers were used to calculate this problem for a $n$ by $n$ grid. In your case $n=5$, we have $a(5)=13698$ according to [A189414](https://oeis.org/A189414).